Set focus on exit button of apex alert box whenever it appears
Is there any way to set focus on exit button of a on alert box whenever its used in oracle apex, so whenever apex alert box appears it focuses on exit icon doesnt matter what triggered it.

Does this get you closer?

maybe  I will try
